# Show category post list on sidebar module on joomla

Tags: php, content-management-system, joomla

i need to show a list of post of a specific category on a module. How can i do? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built-in module called **Latest News** (mod_latestnews).
When configuring the module you will find **Module Parameters** to the right.
Just specify a **Category ID** there.

You can find the Category IDs in the Category Manager.

If you need articles from multiple categories you can separate the IDs with a comma.